# неправильная скобочная последовательность

Tags: python, c++, строки, олимпиада, стек

### Неправильная скобочная последовательность.

Васе подарили строку, состоящую только из цифр от 1 до 6. Он решил превратить эту строку в последовательность круглых, квадратных и фигурных скобок. Для этого каждой цифре он поставил в соответствие скобку по следующему правилу:

1 = {

2 = (

3 = [

4 = }

5 = )

6 = ]

Так он создал скобочную последовательность Braces. Но, к сожалению, эта скобочная последовательность оказалась неправильной. Помогите превратить эту последовательность в правильную, добавив минимально возможное количество скобок.
тут принцип основан на контроле верхушки стека, а не на анализе самой последовательности, то есть: для "1243" будет засчитано "{({}[])}", тогда как "{()}[]" будет правильнее
Python:

```
import sys
from collections import deque

stack = deque()
cout = deque()
for a in sys.stdin.readlines():
    a = a.replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace(' ', '')
    for i in list(a):
        if stack:
            x, y = 0, 0
            if i == '1': y = 1
            elif i == '2': y = 2
            elif i == '3': y = 3
            elif i == '4': y = 4
            elif i == '5': y = 5
            elif i == '6': y = 6
            if stack[-1] == '1': x = 1
            elif stack[-1] == '2': x = 2
            elif stack[-1] == '3': x = 3
            elif stack[-1] == '4': x = 4
            elif stack[-1] == '5': x = 5
            elif stack[-1] == '6': x = 6
            if x + 3 == y:
                stack.pop()
        stack.append(i)
    for i in stack:
        if i == '1':
            print('{', end='')
            cout.appendleft('4')
        elif i == '2':
            print('(', end='')
            cout.appendleft('5')
        elif i == '3':
            print('[', end='')
            cout.appendleft('6')
        elif i == '4': print('{}', end='')
        elif i == '5': print('()', end='')
        elif i == '6': print('[]', end='')
    for i in cout:
        if i == '4': print('}', end='')
        elif i == '5': print(')', end='')
        elif i == '6': print(']', end='')
```

C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;



int main() {
    deque <char> stack(0);
    deque <char> print(0);
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    for (char i : a) {
        if (stack.size() > 0) {
            int x = atoi(&stack.back()), y = atoi(&i);
            if (x + 3 == y) {
                stack.pop_front();
            }
        }
        stack.push_back(i);
    }
    for (char i : stack) {
        if (i == '1') { cout << '{'; print.push_front('4'); }
        if (i == '2') { cout << '('; print.push_front('5'); }
        if (i == '3') { cout << '['; print.push_front('6'); }
        if (i == '4') { cout << "{}"; }
        if (i == '5') { cout << "()"; }
        if (i == '6') { cout << "[]"; }
    }
    for (char i : print) {
        if (i == '4') { cout << '}'; }
        if (i == '5') { cout << ')'; }
        if (i == '6') { cout << ']'; }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

решение неправильное, валится на 4 тестах, сами тесты неизвестны, как улучшить код?[ссылка на курс с задачей](https://stepik.org/course/93079/syllabus) сама задача находится в модуле 1.2 6-ая задача

Comment: По-моему, я уже болел этим дежа вю... Похоже, предыдущие вопросы на эту тему просто удалены.

Comment: ответа я не получил, а решение все же интересно..

Comment: Но в 1.2.6 нет условия "на контроле верхушки стека, а не на анализе самой последовательности"...

Comment: по видео из курса можно понять, что от нас требуют контроля верхушки стека, да и в комментариях об этом говорят

Comment: Да в принципе вроде несложно, но совершенно нет времени... Если до вечера никто не сделает, попробую посмотреть...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, выдрал немного времени, вот решение на С++ (писалось на бегу, можно оптимизировать, и даже существенно, я этого не делал, лишь бы заработало...)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    string r = "123", t = "{([})]", s;
    cin >> s;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (r.find(s[i]) != r.npos) continue;
        // Какая ближайшая непарная?
        bool found = false;
        for(int j = i-1; j >= 0; --j)
        {
            if (!isdigit(s[j])) continue;
            if (s[j] == s[i] - 3)
            {
                s[j] = t[s[j]-'0'-1];
                s[i] = t[s[i]-'0'-1];
                found = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (!found) s[i] += 10;
    }

    for(int i = s.size()-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (isdigit(s[i]))
        {
            s += t[s[i]-'0'-1+3];
            s[i] = t[s[i]-'0'-1];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (isdigit(s[i])) cout << t[s[i]-'0'-1];
        else if (t.find(s[i]) != t.npos) cout << s[i];
        else
        {
            s[i] -= 10;
            cout << t[s[i]-'0'-4] << t[s[i]-'0'-1];
        }
    }
}
```